# syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ';' or '\n'

Tags: ruby

Tried to include a module in another one, but something goes wrong

```
ruby pipboy.rb
pipboy.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ';' or '\n'
def Pipboy < Person
            ^
pipboy.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: You are trying to define a function that inherits from another class. That is not possible. Were you trying to do `class Pipboy <  Person`?

Comment: What is `def Pipboy < Person` supposed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`def` is a keyword to define *methods*. You probably want to *derive* a class/module. This is to be done with:

```
class Pipboy < Person
```

to include (as stated in OP) one module into other, one should use `include` keyword:

```
class Pipboy
  include Person
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `def` keyword is used to create function definitions. What you are thinking of is the `class` keyword.

Make sure you have a `Pipboy` class, and then do `class Pipboy < Person`

Here is more information on inheritance

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html